# textView Nullpointer exception when casted in similar conditions

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-tablayout

***Background***

I am populating the textview and imageview dynamically for standarized fragments.
Instead of creating 6 Fragment Layouts and activities, I created 3 and I am setting text/images as needed. This way I would be able to save time and memory instead of creating one fragment per activity when the only thing that changes is the text in the textView and imageView.

***Problem***

When it reaches the Fragment 3, I get a nullpointer when the implementation is the same as FragmenFirst,FragmentSecond and I do not why.

***Code***

Page adapter which populates the tablayout

```
package com.company.app

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter


class CustomPageAdapter(FragManager:FragmentManager): FragmentPagerAdapter(FragManager) {
    var fragManagerItems:ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    var fragManagerTitles:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    fun removeFragments()
    {
    fragManagerItems.clear()
    }
    fun addFragments(fragmentItem:Fragment,fragmentTitle:String)
    {
    fragManagerItems.add(fragmentItem)
    fragManagerTitles.add(fragmentTitle)

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragManagerItems[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragManagerItems.size
    }
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return fragManagerTitles[position]
    }
```

Fragments are standard, nothing have changed

```
class FragmentFirst : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment "

        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_first, container, false)

    }
```

Second

```
class FragmentSecond : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_second, container, false)
    }


}
```

Third

```
class FragmentThird : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_third, container, false)
    }


}
```

Portion where Main Activity change the textViews of each

```
import android.os.Bundle import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity import android.view.Menu import android.view.MenuItem import com.company.app.fragments.* import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_main.* import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_appbar_main.* import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_fragment_first.* import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_fragment_second.* import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_fragment_third.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    var objPageAdapter:CustomPageAdapter?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar) 
     ...

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        objPageAdapter = CustomPageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_fruits -> {
                objPageAdapter!!.removeFragments()
                objPageAdapter!!.addFragments(FragmentFirst(),getString(R.string.txt_tab_fruits_Element_1))
                objPageAdapter!!.addFragments(FragmentSecond(),getString(R.string.txt_tab_fruits_Element_2))
                objPageAdapter!!.addFragments(FragmentThird(),getString(R.string.txt_tab_fruits_Element_3))
                ViewPagerMain.adapter = objPageAdapter
                TabLayoutMain.setupWithViewPager(ViewPagerMain)
                this.textViewFragment_1.text = getString(R.string.txt_txtView_fruits_Element_1)
                this.textViewFragment_2.text = getString(R.string.txt_txtView_fruits_Element_2)
                this.textViewFragment_3.text = getString(R.string.txt_txtView_fruits_Element_3)

...
```

Error

[image]

Xml Fragment 2 and 3 as sample

Fragment 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.FragmentSecond">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFragment_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_banana" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFragment_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="261dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.FragmentThird">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFragment_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_banana" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFragment_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="261dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***Approaches used***

 1. Clear/Rebuild Project 

 2. Shutdown/Restart PC

***EDIT:Per request, I paste the stacktrace that I am getting***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.company.app, PID: 6790
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: this.textViewFragment_3 must not be null
                      at com.company.app.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:111)
                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:154)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
                      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

***Edit2: To Address Rahul answer***

Embedded code in the Main Activity

```
...
ViewPagerMain.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
                override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
                private lateinit var fr: Fragment
                private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
                private lateinit var textView1:TextView
                private lateinit var textView2:TextView
                private lateinit var textView3:TextView
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    when (position) {
                        0 ->{
                            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.ViewPagerMain + ":" + ViewPagerMain.getCurrentItem())
                            textView1 = fr.textViewFragment_1
                            textView1.text= "test1"
                        }
                        1 ->{
                            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.ViewPagerMain + ":" + ViewPagerMain.getCurrentItem())
                            textView2 = fr.textViewFragment_2
                            textView2.text= "test2"
                        }
                        2 ->{
                            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.ViewPagerMain + ":" + ViewPagerMain.getCurrentItem())
                            textView3.text= "test3"
                        }
```

Comment: If you downvote, care to explain please

Comment: can you post stacktrace which you are getting ?

Comment: @RadekJ I just edited my post with it

Comment: IllegalStateException means your are using `textViewFragment_3` even before Fragment UI created, you should use it in `onViewCreated` method

Comment: Sgdva, above is your answer by @VikasPatidar . Initialize all view elements of the fragments in their onCreateView() method, then return.

Comment: All the elements are created by the  objPageAdapter!!.addFragments function which is handled by the page adapter class. @Danger Yes! That was the only work around or perhaps the only solution as now. 
However I don't understand why is not working on the main class since when adapter class creates the fragments also creates the UI, after these lines `ViewPagerMain.adapter = objPageAdapter
                TabLayoutMain.setupWithViewPager(ViewPagerMain)` should be accesible -as happens with fragmentFirst and Second-

Comment: Afaik the latter is a syntactical issue. You can't have multiple statements in the when statement's "case" without curly brackets: x -> // single statement, 0 -> { // multiple statements }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of accessing textView in onCreate use onPageChangeListener event

```
 private lateinit var fr: Fragment;
private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
private lateinit var textView1:TextView
private lateinit var textView2:TextView
private lateinit var textView3:TextView
override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
    when (position) {
        0 ->{
            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem())

            textView1 = fr.textViewFragment_1
        }



        1-> {
            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem())

            textView2 = fr.textViewFragment_2

            textView2.text = "rr"
        }



        2-> {
            fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem())

            textView3= fr.textViewFragment_3

            textView3.text = "tt"
        }

    }
}

override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout)


}
```

use these lines in onPageselected to get instance of current visible fragment

```
Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(“android:switcher:” + R.id.pager + “:” + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

now you can access textview but check if fr instancOf Fragment1
textView1=fr.findViewById(textview1Id) and so os..........

Comment: Thanks! It is helpful indeed, however, I can't call the textviews on page selected

Comment: Sadly, it causes a null pointer exception too. It works on the first fragment, but when I scroll to the second one causes a nullpointer exception but now on the first one -the one that created itself-. I'll edit my post so you see it.

Comment: 2 problems arise as now: 1-
`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fr has not been initialized` I tried it above the fun as private and inside the function as lateinit only, both crashed.
2-I can't assign the textview in the when, it keeps saying to declare it before, which I tried but it doesn't do anything

Comment: It works! However when changing from one item to the other one it "bugs" and doesn't change the position (int) element at first. Should I open a new question? Or do you think it's related to this?